# Can I consolidate multiple functions that set state based on callbacks from React child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I'm using React hooks to set state. There is a parent component that has multiple child components. The parent component has the state, and passes functions to the children components to update its state as callbacks.

The child components are the same, they just receive different function callbacks to update the related state in the parent.

My question is, can I write one `handleChange` function in the parent that will allow me to use this function callback structure to set multiple state values in the parent?

Parent component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Control from './Control'

const Sort = () => {

  const [controlUpValues, setControlUpValues] = useState([])
  const [controlDownValues, setControlDownValues] = useState([])

  const handleControlUpChange = values => {
    setControlUpValues(values)
  }

  const handleControlDownChange = values => {
    setControlDownValues(values)
  }

  return
    <>
      <Control
        setControlItems={handleControlUpChange}
      />

      <Control
        setControlItems={handleControlDownChange}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default Sort
```

Child component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core'

function Control({ setControlItems }) {
  const [controlInputValues, setControlInputValues] = useState([])
  const [inputRef, setInputRef] = useState([])
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState([])

  const handleValueChange = () => setInputValues(inputRef.value)

  const addValuesToItems = () => {
    setControlItems(inputValues)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        inputRef={ref => setInputRef(ref)}
        value={controlInputValues ? controlInputValues : ''}
        onChange={handleValueChange}
      />
      <Button
        onClick={addValuesToItems}
      >
        Add
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Control
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an object containing the functions to update the state :

**Parent**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Control from './Control'

const Sort = ({ classes }) => {

  const [controlBoostValues, setControlBoostValues] = useState([])
  const [controlBuryValues, setControlBuryValues] = useState([])

  const functions = {
    boost: setControlBoostValues,
    bury: setControlBuryValues
  }

  const handleChange = (key, values) => functions[key](values);

  return
    <>
      <Control
        setControlItems={handleChange}
      />

      <Control
        setControlItems={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

**Child :**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core'

function Control({ setControlItems }) {
  const [controlInputValues, setControlInputValues] = useState([])
  const [inputRef, setInputRef] = useState([])
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState([])

  const handleValueChange = () => setInputValues(inputRef.value)

  const addValuesToItems = () => {
    setControlItems("boost" , inputValues)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        inputRef={ref => setInputRef(ref)}
        value={controlInputValues ? controlInputValues : ''}
        onChange={handleValueChange}
      />
      <Button
        onClick={addValuesToItems}
      >
        Add
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Control
```

Comment: Generally this makes sense, but hardcoding the key in the child?

Comment: There is only one type of child component, and one declared function within it that is called to update items on click, be it boost or bury. I don't see in your suggestion a way to differentiate which items are "boost" vs. "bury" in the callback since there is only one `addValuesToItems` function shared across the child components.

Comment: @Taki is there a way to add this key as an identifier in child declaration vs. setting it within the child? i.e. the child must essentially remain unchanged in functionality that is not shared across all children, so how can the child declaration identifier be set?

Comment: @lane taki named the props backwards, but just do this `setControlItems={values => handleChange('boost', values)}` in the parent. problem solved